# Plotting R in Jupyter lab with dark theme is barely visible

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, jupyter-lab

I am trying to plot using R kernel in Jupyter lab, and I set my Jupyter lab theme as "Jupyterlab dark."

Below is my code:

```
options(repr.plot.width=20, repr.plot.height=5)
plot(x)
points(x2,pch=1,col="blue")
```

This is what I get

[image: When Jupyter lab theme is dark]

Is there a way to make it look more like the plot below? (I switched jupyter lab theme to light, and now the plot is visible)

[image: When Jupyter Lab theme is light]

Comment: In case you didn't manage to solve your issue, I've added an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51196587/2694260) which would solve your issue. In summary go into your Jupyter Lab files, find `variables.css` and edit to your needs (I changed images to have a grey background).

Answer (score 0):

Add this before the plot:

```
par(bg = 'white')
plot(df)
```