# How to edit a JupyterLab theme

Tags: python, themes, jupyter-lab

I'd like to edit the JupyterLab Dark Theme, so that axis labels on inline plots can be clearly read. Example of the problem:
[image: Example of the issue with the Dark theme]

To remedy this problem I'd like to change the background colour of output cells which contain an image to a shade of grey. I used Chrome DevTools to insepect the webpage and found the class `class="p-Widget jp-RenderedImage jp-mod-trusted jp-OutputArea-output"`.

[image: Div class that I'd like to alter]

I've noted that I can workaround this problem by using the JupyterLab Light Theme or by using a dark plotting theme in `matplotlib`, however I'd like to address this issue directly. I welcome all suggestions or directions to resources to read which would help me to understand and fix this. Thanks!

Related issue on GitHub:

- [How to figure out current jupyterlab theme in script imported by notebook #3855](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3855)

Related SO questions:

- [How to edit jupyter lab theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988458/how-to-edit-jupyter-lab-theme)
- [Plotting R in Jupyter lab with dark theme is barely visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929766/plotting-r-in-jupyter-lab-with-dark-theme-is-barely-visible?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To edit JupypterLab themes you need to make changes to the file [`variables.css`](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/theme-dark-extension/style/variables.css) which is located in `jupyterlab/packages/[THEME NAME]/style/`

You can inspect the element of the JupyterLab that you'd like to change to find out its class. I used Chrome DevTools `ctrl+shift+i` and click on various div classes until I found the one I wanted to alter.

Once you have the name of the div class you'd like to customize, add the changes to the `variables.css` file. Here's what I changed and the result.

```
.jp-RenderedImage {
  background-color: #A4A4A4
}
```

[image: Change background of figures to grey to allow axis to be read]

You can use [this gist (where the code in the first cell comes from)](https://gist.github.com/jasongrout/753216b2d3320b0abec6143d36f5d640) created by one of the JupyterLab contributors to experiment with changes you made to the `variables.css` file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the example you show is because the plot's `facecolor` is transparent. I noticed this happened for my plots too when I switched to Jupyter's Dark Theme.

Here are two references for updating this Jupyter configuration:

1. [Enable white frames on matplotlib figure/ Disable transparent frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371499/enable-white-frames-on-matplotlib-figure-disable-transparent-frames)
2. https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html

In summary, I opened the `~/.ipython/profile_default` directory and created a new `ipython_config.py` file (because it wasn't already there)

```sh
cd ~/.ipython/profile_default/
vi ipython_config.py
```

In that file, I added the lines

```py
c = get_config()
c.InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs={'facecolor' : "w"}
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `~/.ipython` ?