# Jupyter Notebook theme not following normal python script theme in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, themes

I'm using the Dark+ (default dark) theme in VS code for my normal python script writing. I recently started learning Jupyter Notebook with a course I'm taking and quickly realized that although the Jupyter notebook theme is very similar to the theme for python, it's not exactly the same. It's missing some colors.

[image: Default Python]

As you can see "pandas" "pd" are teal (greenish blue), while "df" is light blue.

[image: jupyter notebook]

However all of those words in jupyter are completely white.

I tried playing around with other themes and the same issue is there. Not sure what's the issue and how can I fix it. I'm running it on a local machine on windows. Not using WSL, I think I had read that this is an issue with WSL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit a JupyterLab theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51191993/7758804)

Answer (score 0):

The `Jupyter Notebook` in the VSCode lack of the support of `Semantic Token Colorization`. Like this:

[image]

[image]

The JupyterNoteBook lacks this feature for now. You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7225) for more details.