# How to edit background color of jupyterlab's output for better visualization of figure

Tags: colors, background, output, jupyter-lab

Problem: cannot see texts of figure axes in dark mode of jupyterlab

[image]

Desire: less dark color of output (or whole) in dark mode

I have check this post [How to edit a JupyterLab theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191993/how-to-edit-a-jupyterlab-theme)
but there is no variables.css file in the Jupyterlab folder (web version 3.2.1).

Instead, I found this file for style, but have no idea which code is for 'output background' C:\Users<username>\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\themes@jupyterlab\theme-dark-extension\index.css

very much appreciated for any help :)